# Why is this program asking for more input than needed?

Tags: c++

It is a simple program to calculate the next number of a given number by adding one to it. By during execution it asks more inputs than needed and gives a wrong result. But when I give input through file, it gives right answer. I tried debugging but only thing i found was my input loop was running more than the number of times i specified. I am a newbie to this. Please help.

```
//Simple program to add 1 to the number given. Digits in number can be upto 10^9
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#define DD cout<<"Working!"
using namespace std;
void JNEXT()
{
    long n;//total length of the digits, you will give
    cin>>n;

    long all_nine=0;//for checking whether all are nine or not
    long a[n+1]={0};//initializing the array with zero

    for(long i=0;i<n;i++)//taking input and storing in a[]
        {
            cin>>a[i];
            if(a[i]==9)
                all_nine++;
            DD;
        }

    if(all_nine==n)//if all digits are nine then print next number by adding one
    {
        cout<<1;
        for(long i=0;i<n;i++)
            cout<<0;
        cout<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        int carry=1;
        for(long i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
                a[i]+=carry;
                if(a[i]==10)
                    a[i]=0;
                else carry=0;
        }
        for(long i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<a[i];
        cout<<endl; 
    }
}

int main()
{
    int t;//Number of Queries you want to check(process)
    cin>>t;
    while(t-- > 0)
        JNEXT();
return 0;
}
```

Edits: I got the answer Thanks!

Comment: You say you want to input individual digits, but `cin>>a[i]` reads a complete multi-digit integer from the stream. You read `n` integers, not `n` digits.

Comment: Yes I got it, Thanks

Comment: When reading an integral type reading stops on the first non-digit. Note that your file input has spaces after each digit. You should also **always** check if input was successful, e.g., using `if (std::cin >> a[i]) { /* deal with successful read */ } else { /* deal with failure */ }`. Finally note that variable sized arrays on the stack (`long a[n];`) are not supported by standard C++ (they are an extension in some compilers).